# Whitespaces in logic statement throw an error

Tags: ruby

I have the following piece of Ruby code (Ruby 2.1.2):

```
x = false
y = true
!(x || y)
```

It throws a

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` y' for main:Object
```

However, this line works

```
x = true
y = false
!(x || y)
=> false
```

I can explain this, because `x` is already true, and so `y` isn't evaluated.

Now it gets interesting. When I write

```
x = false
y = true
!(x||y)
=> false
```

everything works as expected. But can someone explain, why I have to strip out the two whitespaces in `x || y`?

Comment: Issue cannot be reproduced in `ruby-2.0.0-p598`

Comment: I have `ruby-2.1.2` and updated that information in my question

Comment: Cannot reproduce on either `ruby-2.0.0-p598` or `ruby 2.1.5p273`.

Comment: 2.1.2p95 (OSX) works as expected

Comment: Works well on ruby 2.1.3p242

Comment: Ok, then I try to simply reinstall ruby

Comment: The original code probably contains a [Unicode space](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-split-is-not-enough-whitespace-shenigans-for-rubyists-5980.html) (check it with a hex editor). Maybe SO “corrected” it or can you reproduce the error with the code on this site?

Comment: @cremno It **does contain** Unicode space. Edit ⇒ copypaste to vim clearly shows it.

Comment: @mudasobwa unfortunately, SO sanitizes certain characters when rendering code, making it difficult to discuss or even reproduce such issues.

Comment: @Stefan Fortunately, SO leaves the _entered text_ untouched, so you might click “edit” to open the issue text _exactly as it was entered_, than copy-paste it in your favorite editor and make sure that there is a non-ascii.

Comment: @mudasobwa yeah, that's what I meant by "difficult" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression contains a special whitespace character, probably a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

```
!(x || y)
#     ^
#     |
#   here
```

The error message shows it, too:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method ' y' for main:Object
#                                              ^
#                                              |
#                                             here
```

Comment: Thanks, another thing learned. From now, I activate invisible characters in my editor ;)